# Set localstorage for array of elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I need to set an array of objects values to localstorage using vanilla JavaScript.

I have tried looping through the array and getting each index then setting each index it doesn't seem to work. However if i single reference each element it works, which is strange...

```
const theme_cache = [document.getElementById('panel').style.background,document.getElementsByClassName('icon-bar')[0].style.color]

     const saved_theme_cache = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cached-elements'));

    element.onchange = function(){
         localStorage.setItem('cached-elements', JSON.stringify(theme_cache));
    }
```

Comment: localStorage is a key/value pair and accepts only strings as value parameters. When passed something else, it will call it's `toString` representation. You should use JSON.stringify and JSON.parse to serialize/deserialize the value

Comment: You can use `JSON.stringify()` to store the array as a JSON string and `JSON.parse()` to restore the array of objects from the stored string.

Answer (score 3):

`localStorage` is a key/value pair and accepts only `strings` as value parameters. When passed something else, it will call it's `toString()` representation. You should use JSON.stringify and JSON.parse to serialize/deserialize the value.

```
const listOfTests = [{test: "test"}]
localStorage.setItem("tests", JSON.stringify(listOfTests));

const listOfTestsFromLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tests"))
```

Comment: Please do not update your code in the original post, users need to know how relevant the answers are.

Comment: Your code will store the new values when `element` has changed. You need a handler to retrieve them. This code will only retrieve them on `page load`, once. We cannot help much as the snippet does not give enough scope of what you are trying to accomplish. You have to call `getItem(x)` everytime you want to retrieve the latest value of the localStorage. It will not update itself.